# What is the recommended way to provide an API for Apache Spark application results

Tags: api, hadoop, apache-spark

We have a huge set of data stored on hadoop cluster. We need to do some analysis to these data using apache spark and provide the result of this analysis to other applications via an API.

I have two ideas but I can not figure out which one is the recommended.

The first option is to make spark application(s) that make its analysis and store the result in another datastore (relation DB or even HDFS), then develop another application that reads the result of the analysis from the other datastore and provide an API for querying.

The second option is to make merge the two applications into one application. This way I deduce the need to another datastore but I this way the application will up running all the time.

What is the recommended way to go for in this situation? and if there is another options kindly list it.

Comment: There are several questions to answer:
Storing or not storing the end result: how much data will be generated as output? Just some statistics or a whole new dataset)? How will you handle the fact that output is not immediately avaible? How will you handle processing failures?
One or two applications: how coupled (release/deployment lifecycle) would they be? Spark adds some constraints on packaging (uberjar for instance), is it tolerable for your second application? Will you run Spark driver app in client mode or cluster mode?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on How frequently the user going to hit the get api.as if client want real time result should go for in line api.else can use first aproach of storing result in another data storage.